# Replacing index range in String with certain character - Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to replace the entire string with '#' except the last 4 characters.

The following:

```
def maskify(cc):
    c2 = cc.replace(cc[:-4], '#')
    return c2

print(maskify('TestName'))
```

Results in:

```
#Name
```

I want it to return:

```
####Name
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simpler solution you could instead use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) on the last `4` characters of the string, and fill it with `#` up to its original length:

```
s = 'TestName'
s[-4:].rjust(len(s), '#')

'####Name'
```

---

The problem with your function, is that you have to repeat the elements you want to use to replace as many times as replacements there will be. So you should do:

```
def maskify(cc):
    c2 = cc.replace(cc[:-4], '#'*len(cc[:-4]))
    return c2
```

Answer (score 1):

yatu's solution using `rjust()` looks good, but `str.replace()` is a false friend. It works for `a reasonably varied string`, but if elements are repeated in the string it can fail (this is yatu's 2nd solution):

```
def maskify(cc):
    c2 = cc.replace(cc[:-4], '#'*len(cc[:-4]))
    return c2

print(maskify('12121212'))
```

gives,

```
########
```

I suggest 'building' the new string like this instead,

```
def maskify(cc):
    mask = '#' * (len(cc)-4)
    return mask+cc[-4:]
```

which gives the desired result,

```
####1212
```